# symfony2 payum paypal express simple checkout

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payum

I'm new to Payum. A lot thing quite confuse to me. I'm try to build up a simple paypal express checkout like the example show on the Payum [document](http://payum.org/doc/0.11/PayumBundle/simple_purchase_examples/paypal_express_checkout).However, when I tried to process the payment, it shows up an exception:

**"Payum payment named my_paypal_express_checkout does not exist.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException"**

Here is the config:

```
payum:
security:
    token_storage:
        Acme\PaymentBundle\Entity\PayumSecurityToken:
            doctrine:
                driver: orm
storages:
    Acme\PaymentBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails:
        doctrine: 
            driver: orm

contexts:
    Ibase_paypal_express:
        paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
         ...codes...
```

Here are the code of prepare and done action in controller:

```
public function preparePaypalAction(Request $request)
{
    $paymentName = 'ibase_paypal_express_checkout';

    $form = $this->createPurchaseForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('Ibase\PaymentBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails');

        /** @var \Ibase\CartBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails $paymentDetails */
        $paymentDetails = $storage->createModel();
        $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = $data['currency'];
        $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = $data['amount'];//total amount ??
        $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);

        $captureToken = $this->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(
            $paymentName,
            $paymentDetails,
            'payment_done' // the route to redirect after capture;
        );

        $paymentDetails['INVNUM'] = $paymentDetails->getId();
        $paymentDetails['RETURNURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
        $paymentDetails['CANCELURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
        $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);

        return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }
    return $this->render('PaymentBundle:PaypalExpress:paypalPrepare.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'paymentName' => $paymentName
    ));
}

public function doneAction(Request $request)
{
    $token = $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($request);

    $payment = $this->get('payum')->getPayment($token->getPaymentName());

    $status = new BinaryMaskStatusRequest($token);
    $payment->execute($status);

    if ($status->isSuccess()) {
        $this->getUser()->addCredits(100);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set(
            'notice',
            'Payment success. Credits were added'
        );
    } else if ($status->isPending()) {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set(
            'notice',
            'Payment is still pending. Credits were not added'
        );
    } else {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('error', 'Payment failed');
    }

    return $this->redirect('home');
}

 /**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form
 */
protected function createPurchaseForm()
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('amount', null, array(
            'data' => 1,
            'constraints' => array(new Range(array('max' => 2)))
        ))
        ->add('currency', null, array('data' => 'AUD'))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

Anyone can help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your YML file

```
contexts:
    Ibase_paypal_express:
```

and your code :

```
$paymentName = 'ibase_paypal_express_checkout';
```

Notice the capital 'I' and string name? Those two names/values should be the same. 
So either

```
$paymentName = 'Ibase_paypal_express';
```

or

```
contexts:
    ibase_paypal_express_checkout:
```

Comment: Thanks @Qemal Stafa ! It might because of my poor understanding of English, I did not get any hints by the document show they should be the same. Any way, Thanks again!